# How to ascii to hex and send with bluetooth?

Tags: android

I have a hex file `example.bin`. It include just like `"0031....."` numbers and if i open ascii file show me like this `".1..."` A mean `00 = .` and `31=1`,so 2 characters shows us 1 ascii number. 
If i read on the android like a Stringbuilder (because my data very large) than i saw meaningless values � � on the app. But i want to show hex numbers or true ascii numbers.  And than i want to send these values with bluetooth but i have many erorr. How can i fixed ?
I used this code

```
InputStream  is =this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.blink);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is));
            send =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.send);

             if(is!=null){

            try {
                while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    char [] ch =data.toCharArray();

                    for (char c: ch) {
                        int i= (int) c;
                        sbuffer.append(Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase());
                        text.setText(sbuffer);

                    }

                }

                is.close();

            }
             catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(sbuffer!=null) {
                    byte[] bytes = text.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                    mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

My bluetooth send part:

```
//Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
```

Log.cat:

```
   Process: com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist, PID: 20754
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist.BluetoothConnectionService.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist.OTA_Update$1.onClick(OTA_Update.java:82)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21215)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```